# utf8_encode or decode isn't doing what I expect

Tags: php, utf-8, utf8-decode

I am taking an XML file and reading it into various strings, before writing to a database, however I am having difficulty with German characters.

The XML file starts off

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Then an example of where I am having problems is this part

```
<name><![CDATA[PONS Großwörterbuch Deutsch als Fremdsprache Android]]></name>
```

My PHP has this relevant section

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$domNode = $xmlReader->expand();
$element = $dom->appendChild($domNode);
$domString = utf8_encode($dom->saveXML($element));
$product = new SimpleXMLElement($domString);

//read in data
$arr = $product->attributes();
$link_ident = $arr["id"];
$link_id =  $platform . "" . $link_ident;
$link_name = $product->name;
```

So $link_name becomes PONS GroÃwÃ¶rterbuch Deutsch als Fremdsprache Android

I then did a

```
$link_name = utf8_decode($link_name);
```

Which when I echoed back in terminal worked fine

```
PONS GroÃwÃ¶rterbuch Deutsch als Fremdsprache Android as is now 
PONS Großwörterbuch Deutsch als Fremdsprache Android after utf8decode
```

However when it is written into my database it appears as:

PONS KompaktwÃ¶rterbuch Deutsch-Englisch (Android)

The collation for link_name in MysQL is utf8_general_ci

How should I be doing this to get it correctly written into my database?

This is the code I use to write to the database

```
$link_name = utf8_decode($link_name);
$link_id = mysql_real_escape_string($link_id);
$link_name = mysql_real_escape_string($link_name);
$description = mysql_real_escape_string($description);
$metadesc = mysql_real_escape_string($metadesc);
$link_created = mysql_real_escape_string($link_created);
$link_modified = mysql_real_escape_string($link_modified);
$website = mysql_real_escape_string($website);
$cost = mysql_real_escape_string($cost);
$image_name = mysql_real_escape_string($image_name);
$query = "REPLACE into jos_mt_links
(link_id, link_name, alias, link_desc, user_id, link_published,link_approved, metadesc, link_created, link_modified, website, price)
VALUES ('$link_id','$link_name','$link_name','$description','63','1','1','$metadesc','$link_created','$link_modified','$website','$cost')";
echo $link_name . " has been inserted ";
```

and when I run it from shell I see

```
PONS Kompaktwörterbuch Deutsch-Englisch (Android) has been inserted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a UTF-8 string from an XML file, and you're putting it into a UTF-8 database. So there is no encoding or decode to be done, just shove the original string into the database. Make sure you've used `mysql_set_charset('utf-8')` first to tell the database there are UTF-8 strings coming.

`utf8_decode` and `utf8_encode` are misleadingly named. They are *only* for converting between UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 encodings. Calling `utf8_decode`, which converts to ISO-8859-1, will naturally lose any characters you have that don't fit in that encoding. You should generally avoid these functions unless there's a specific place where you need to be using 8859-1.

You should not consider what the terminal shows when you echo a string to be definitive. The terminal has its own encoding problems and especially under Windows it is likely to be impossible to output every character properly. On a Western Windows install the system code page (which the terminal will use to turn the bytes PHP spits out into characters to display on-screen) will be code page 1252, which is similar to but not the same as ISO-8859-1. This is why `utf8_decode`, which spits out ISO-8859-1, appeared to make the text appear as you expected. But that's of little use. Internally you should be using UTF-8 for all strings.

Comment: thanks bob, so I changed the line that did the utf8_encode to just be $domString = $dom->saveXML($element);
and deleted the utf8_decode line, and added mysql_Set_charset and it has worked :)

Answer (score 1):

You must use mb_convert_encoding or iconv unction before you write into your database.

Comment: Thanks, but how will that help when I have utf8 and I am writing into a utf8 field in a database?